# CSS div fixed height, min width but expands width on content

Tags: javascript, css

The title says it all really, but despite several tries I cant actually get this to work.

Im looking for a DIV to have a fixed height, and min-width, I will display text in the div (dynamically changing), should any text be long enough to reach the bottom of DIV I want the the width of the div to increase to accomodate all the text.

Is there a CSS solution ?

Comment: Not possible with CSS AFAIK. You'd need javascript.

Comment: Yes Im begining to think that too @Paulie_D .. I just couldnt believe that it wasnt possible with pure CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so its not possible to do this in CSS, so Javascript is the way to go.

For anyone else searching for a similar solution here is the javascript routine that I built to give me the functionality I required.

Basically it checks if the div is in overflow and if so increases the width by 5% increments until the overflow is resolved, if on load the div isnt in overflow it decreases the width by 5% until it finds the overflow point then steps back one notch.

```
function changedivsize(){
    widthmin = 35; // in percent
    widthmax = 80; // in percent
    modified = false; // flag to signify when wheve modified the div larger
    while ( $("#quotation").prop('scrollHeight') > $("#quotation").height() ) { // if div is in overflow
        modified = true;                // set flag so we dont start making div smaller in section below
        var widthpixels = $('#quotation').width(); 
        var parentWidth = $('#quotation').offsetParent().width();
        var widthpercent = 100*widthpixels/parentWidth;  // find current width % of div (3lines)
        if (widthpercent < widthmax) {  // if not at limit
            widthpercent = Math.round(widthpercent+5);  // add 5%
            $("#quotation").width(widthpercent+"%");  // change div width
        }else{
            break;  // if we are at limit call it a day
        }   
    } // repeat adding 5% until either we are out of overload or at limit


    while (modified == false){ // basically same as above but reduce div for smaller texts
        var widthpixels = $('#quotation').width();
        var parentWidth = $('#quotation').offsetParent().width();
        var widthpercent = 100*widthpixels/parentWidth;
        if (widthpercent > widthmin) {
            widthpercent = Math.round(widthpercent-5);
            $("#quotation").width(widthpercent+"%");  // change div width
            if ( $("#quotation").prop('scrollHeight') > $("#quotation").height() ){
                widthpercent = widthpercent+5;
                $("#quotation").width(widthpercent+"%");  // change div width
                break;
            }
        }else{
            break;
        }   
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered, here is what I got

https://jsfiddle.net/Lu3tu98b/2/

```
div{
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.myDiv {
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Could you please provide your code.

Comment: Thanks but how does that relate to my question ? 
You've put scroll bars on the div, I dont want the div to scroll, I want the WIDTH to change to accomodate the longer text and the height to stay fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Is this good for what you need?

http://jsfiddle.net/KefJ2/343/

```
#container { 
   position: relative; /* needed for absolutely positioning #a and #c */ 
   padding: 0; /* will offset for width of #a and #c; and center #b */
   border: green 3px dotted; /* just for the show */   
   float: left; /* To dynamicaly change width according to children */
   height: 300px;
}

#a { 
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: No, all youve given me is the answer to someone elses problem that I had already read before I posted, but the problem isnt the same.